# how to define gtest ASSERT_ASSERT macro

Tags: c++, googletest

I am defining my own `ASSERT` macro - say `ASSERT_FOO`.

It is very complicated, it changes its behavior based on macro definitions, etc. I would like to create tests to test it. I need something like `ASSERT_ASSERT(ASSERT_FOO(foo()))`;

To achieve this I need something like test reset that eliminates accumulated asserts and the test succeeds.

```
if (::testing::Test::HasFatalFailure()) {
    // reset the test ?
} else {
    FAIL();
}
```

How I can achive this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Substitute non-verbose assert() macro
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640730/
#ifndef assert
    #include <cstdlib> // abort()
    static int assert_count     =  0; // count assertion failures
    const unsigned ASSERT_COUNT = 15; // when to stop assertion executions
    /** (cond ? () : cout << "cond" ) */
    #define assert(cond)    \
        do {                \
            if (!(cond)) {  \
                std::cout << ":" << __LINE__ << " fail-> " #cond "\n";  \
                assert_count++;                                 \
                if ( ASSERT_COUNT==assert_count ) { abort(); }  \
            }                                                   \
        } while (false)
#endif

/** "C:/DIR/SubDir/file_name.ext" ==> "file_name.ext" */
const char* remove_dir_name( const char* str ) {
    const char *p = str;     /* p = str+strlen(str); */
    while ( *p != 0 ) { ++p; }
    while ( *p != '/' && *p != '\\' && *p != ':' ) {
        if ( p == str ) { return str; }
        --p;
    }
    return p+1;
}
```